# Difference between main and test recovering from panic?

Tags: testing, go, error-handling

I have the following snippet which recovers from index out of range panics

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sLxinIkEC_), also pasted below

The error is nil when called from main but not nil in an equivalent test case. What's the difference ?

```
type Foo struct {
    Is []int
}

func main() {
    fp := &Foo{}
    if err := fp.Panic(); err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error: %v", err)
    } 
    fmt.Println("ok")
}

func (fp *Foo) Panic() (err error) {
    defer PanicRecovery(&err)
    fp.Is[0] = 5
    return nil
}

func PanicRecovery(err *error) {

        if r := recover(); r != nil {
                if _, ok := r.(runtime.Error); ok {
            //fmt.Println("Panicing")
                    *err = r.(error) //panic(r)
                } else {
            *err = r.(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
func TestPanic(t *testing.T) {
    fp := &Foo{}
    if err := fp.Panic(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Panic: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the nested line of your main function from:

```
fmt.Errorf("Error: %v", err)
```

To:

```
fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
```

Notice that the ["Errorf"](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf) function doesn't print anything to stdout. It creates an error by formatting the text and arguments you provide and simply returns that error. What you really want is ["fmt.Printf"](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf).